# Placing the Search icon under the Mobile menu

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Unfortunately, I am doing something wrong.  I have a function. In this function the hamburger menu is displayed. I still want to show the search icon under the menu. But as soon as I add the a tag and no span the search icon is shown somewhere under the menu see photo. But if I change the a tag to a span then the search button does not work anymore. What am I doing wrong. Can someone help me.

```php
if ( ! function_exists( 'tonda_select_get_mobile_navigation_icon_html' ) ) {
    /**
     * Loads mobile navigation icon HTML
     */
    function tonda_select_get_mobile_navigation_icon_html() {

        $mobile_icon_icon_source    = tonda_select_options()->getOptionValue( 'mobile_icon_icon_source' );
        $mobile_icon_icon_pack      = tonda_select_options()->getOptionValue( 'mobile_icon_icon_pack' );
        $mobile_icon_svg_path       = tonda_select_options()->getOptionValue( 'mobile_icon_svg_path' );

        $mobile_navigation_icon_html = '';

        if ( ( $mobile_icon_icon_source == 'icon_pack' ) && ( isset( $mobile_icon_icon_pack ) ) ) {
            $mobile_navigation_icon_html .= tonda_select_icon_collections()->getMobileMenuIcon($mobile_icon_icon_pack);
        } else if ( $mobile_icon_icon_source == 'predefined' ) {

            $mobile_navigation_icon_html .= '<span class="qodef-mm-icons-columns">';
            $mobile_navigation_icon_html .= '<span class="qodef-mm-icons col1">';
            $mobile_navigation_icon_html .= '<span class="qodef-mm-line qodef-mm-line-1"></span>';
            $mobile_navigation_icon_html .= '<span class="qodef-mm-line qodef-mm-line-2"></span>';
            $mobile_navigation_icon_html .= '<span class="qodef-mm-line qodef-mm-line-3"></span>';
            $mobile_navigation_icon_html .= '</span>';

            $mobile_navigation_icon_html .= '<span class="qodef-mm-icons col2">';
            $mobile_navigation_icon_html .= '<a class="qodef-search-opener qodef-icon-has-hover qodef-search-opener-icon-pack" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="qodef-search-opener-wrapper">
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="qodef-icon-font-elegant icon_search "></span>                           </span>
        </a>';
            $mobile_navigation_icon_html .= '</span>';
            $mobile_navigation_icon_html .= '</span>';

        } else if ( isset( $mobile_icon_svg_path ) ) {
            $mobile_navigation_icon_html .= $mobile_icon_svg_path;
        }

        return $mobile_navigation_icon_html;
    }
}
```